# How can I use jquery to parse out the font-awesome cheet sheet to key value pairs

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, font-awesome

I want to get the font awesome icon cheat sheet into a sort of key value format (csv is fine) to port to another platform

the sheet is here

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

I can get all the elements holding each icon and the code but I dont know how to get the text out

```
 var elements = $('div.container .row .span4');


$.each(elements, function(el) {

var iconCode = $('span.muted',$(this)).text(); //icon code

//need icon name


console.log(iconCode);
});
```


    icon-star-half
    (&#xf089;)

so I want to pull the text "icon-star-half" somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text = $('.span4').clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();    //get the text of element);
```

Source:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/